# Android: Two Dependencies, Each One Depends on Same Component, Triggers DexArchiveMergerException

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, dex

I have a situation in which my project consists of two different libraries that apparently has a dependency on the same component:

**gradle.build of the client app:**

```
android {
...
}

dependencies {
...
implementation <dependency # 1>
implementation <dependency # 2>
...
}
```

The error that I am seeing:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
```

The Android issue in question:

```
Program type already present: <package name>.<Component>
```

We've recently made gradle changes to one of these dependencies in hopes of eliminating this error:

**build.gradle - dependency # 1**

```
android {
...
}

dependencies {
...
api <dependency # 1>
api <dependency # 2>
...
}
```

But this change apparently has no affect on the outcome.

We have multidex enabled. This property also has no affect on the outcome.

I even went as far as adding this block of code to the gradle file of my client app:

```
configurations {
    runtime.exclude group: "<package name>", module: "<problem module>"
}
```

per examples provided here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_types.html

I'm beginning to run low on options.

Is it possible to make a gradle configuration change to one, multiple, or all of the gradle files in order to put a stop to this? If so, what options do I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a dependency exists in two different dependencies of a single module such that the same package name exists, you can forget about building the client app. For example:

```
Dependency # 1 -> classes.jar -> <some package name> -> Component
Dependency # 2 -> classes.jar -> <THE SAME package name> -> Component
```

If you have access to modify the two libraries, you will be forced to change the package name of one of them. There's no way around it, no way out of it.